# Sending image data to neural network in NEAT but I need to retain colour?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, opencv

I'm currently trying to use retro gym and neat to create a neural network that will play Dr Robotniks Mean Bean Machine.

```
import retro
import numpy as np
import cv2
import neat
import pickle

env = retro.make('DrRobotniksMeanBeanMachine-Genesis')
imgarray = []

def eval_genomes(genomes, config):

    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        ob = env.reset()   # start obs view
        ac = env.action_space.sample()   # action

        inx, iny, inc = env.observation_space.shape    # screen resolution
        inx = int(inx/8)
        iny = int(iny/8)
        print(inc)
        net = neat.nn.recurrent.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome, config)     # create NN

        current_max_fitness = 0
        fitness_current = 0
        frame = 0
        counter = 0
        score = 0
        score_aim = 1000
        score_max = 0
        finished = False

        done = False
        while not done:
            env.render()
            frame += 1
            # image rendering for NN
            ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx, iny))
            ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ob = np.reshape(ob, (inx, iny))

            for x in ob:
                for y in x:
                    imgarray.append(y)

            nnOutput = net.activate(imgarray)

            ob, rew, done, info = env.step(nnOutput)

            imgarray.clear()
            score = info['score']
            if score > score_max:
                fitness_current += 1
                score_max = score
            if score > score_aim:
                fitness_current += 100000
                done = True
            if fitness_current > current_max_fitness:
                current_max_fitness = fitness_current
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1

            if done or counter == 40:
                done = True
                print(genome_id, fitness_current)

            genome.fitness = fitness_current


config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                     neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                     'config-feedforward')

p = neat.Population(config)

winner = p.run(eval_genomes)
with open('winner.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(winner, output, 1)
```

This works, however it is very slow and I fear that looking at what it is viewing it is unable to differentiate between the different beans. I know that each bean has a shape that corresponds to it's colour, however I think the image data is too compressed for the neural network to see this.

Is there anyway to allow the neural network to see in colour? When I try using a different cv2 colour conversion like BGR2HSL, it advises me that the numpy array cannot be resized to fit. I fiddled with the screen resolution a bit but the numbers jump around wildly. Here's an example error message:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3360 into shape (28,40)

If anyone has any experience or suggestions, or could point me in the right direction for a solution I'd be grateful!

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that a colored grid must be resized to (3, 28, 40) because it has 3 channels.

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha Sorry I didn't respond sooner, this is probably the reason.. I wasn't thinking about it being 3 dimensional. Do you know of any way for me to implement this in the above context?